# Sound eXchange (Sox) transformation of files, individually and in batches

Tags: batch-file, audio

I am new to programming (just a little bit of python), and I am trying to run a tutotrial that first needs files in wav format. My directory has a bunch of .au files that I am trying to transform to .wav :

```
tony@VirtualBox:/media/sf_Dropbox/data/genres/classical$ ls
classical.00001.au  classical.00018.au  classical.00035.au  classical.00052.au  classical.00069.au  classical.00086.au
classical.00002.au  classical.00019.au  classical.00036.au  classical.00053.au  classical.00070.au  classical.00087.au
classical.00003.au  classical.00020.au  classical.00037.au  classical.00054.au  classical.00071.au  classical.00088.au
classical.00004.au  classical.00021.au  classical.00038.au  classical.00055.au  classical.00072.au  classical.00089.au
classical.00005.au  classical.00022.au  classical.00039.au  classical.00056.au  classical.00073.au  classical.00090.au
classical.00006.au  classical.00023.au  classical.00040.au  classical.00057.au  classical.00074.au  classical.00091.au
classical.00007.au  classical.00024.au  classical.00041.au  classical.00058.au  classical.00075.au  classical.00092.au
classical.00008.au  classical.00025.au  classical.00042.au  classical.00059.au  classical.00076.au  classical.00093.au
classical.00009.au  classical.00026.au  classical.00043.au  classical.00060.au  classical.00077.au  classical.00094.au
classical.00010.au  classical.00027.au  classical.00044.au  classical.00061.au  classical.00078.au  classical.00095.au
classical.00011.au  classical.00028.au  classical.00045.au  classical.00062.au  classical.00079.au  classical.00096.au
classical.00012.au  classical.00029.au  classical.00046.au  classical.00063.au  classical.00080.au  classical.00097.au
classical.00013.au  classical.00030.au  classical.00047.au  classical.00064.au  classical.00081.au  classical.00098.au
classical.00014.au  classical.00031.au  classical.00048.au  classical.00065.au  classical.00082.au  classical.00099.au
classical.00015.au  classical.00032.au  classical.00049.au  classical.00066.au  classical.00083.au  classical.au
classical.00016.au  classical.00033.au  classical.00050.au  classical.00067.au  classical.00084.au  classical.wav
classical.00017.au  classical.00034.au  classical.00051.au  classical.00068.au  classical.00085.au
```

But when running the sox command, I get this:

```
tony@VirtualBox:/media/sf_Dropbox/data/genres/classical$ sox classical.0000.au classical.0000.wav
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `classical.0000.au': No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know what's happening? Also, how can I run sox for a whole batch instead of one by one?

Comment: My example refers to file classical.0000.au but the problem is the same with any file..

Comment: Can you paste the sox invocation and error for a file that exists?

Comment: Problem solved, I was using a wrong filename. (rookie mistake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking up the documentation for sox, it looks like 'sox classical.00001.au classical.00001.wav' might work.  From the ls output, there is no file called classical.0000.au in that directory, but there is one called classical.00001.au.

Comment: is the problem the same with all the files?

Comment: Yes. it is the same with all the files.

Comment: My mistake. I was using the wrong file name..newbie mistake. Txs.